# how to get process id of a spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, pid

I noticed spring boot printed the process id in the log during it's startup. Now I want write a script to kill this process using this pid and start the application  again. Does Spring Boot provide any api to get this pid? Thanks!

Comment: Windows or Linux?

Comment: @AmrArafat Windows

Comment: The process id is written to file. You can read this file to get the pid.

Comment: @M.Deinum which file?:)

Comment: @M.Deinum is it enabled by default? The docs (for 1.4.2) state, that it isn't.

Comment: If you have the actuator on the classpath it will write it to file by default. By default it writes to `application.pid`.

Comment: I just checked with a small example with web and actuator starter, and without explicitly adding the writer as listener like in my answer, the file isn't created (with Spring Boot 1.4.2).

Comment: Hmm. I would have sworn I have seen a `spring.factories` in either boot or the actuator that registered that listener by default. I probably need a new pair of glasses or a good night sleep :(.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Spring Boot provides the class `ApplicationPidFileWriter`, which will then write the PID into a file. You can activate it by adding it as a listener to the SpringApplication:

```java
SpringApplication springApplication = new SpringApplication(DemoApplication.class);
springApplication.addListeners(new ApplicationPidFileWriter());
springApplication.run(args);
```

The constructor of `ApplicationPidFileWriter` can also take a String or a `File` object with a custom filename. Then you can read the PID from that file and use it in your scripts.

Comment: this is not working for me. Log is also written to pid file. Have you come across such a situation?

Comment: Create a new question and provide the relevant details (code snippets etc.).

Comment: To add some more detail to the answer, you can configure the location of this file by providing the --spring.pidfile parameter when launching your application

Answer (score 3):

`System.getProperty("PID")`  get SPRING BOOT PID.

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Uaqd.png)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkK7S.png)

Comment: Please add your code in the answer not as a link to an image.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Part V. Spring Boot Actuator: Production-ready features documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-process-monitoring.html) :

> In the spring-boot module, you can find two classes to create files
>   that are often useful for process monitoring:
>
> - ApplicationPidFileWriter creates a file containing the application PID
>     (by default, in the application directory with a file name of
>     application.pid).
> - WebServerPortFileWriter creates a file (or files)
>     containing the ports of the running web server (by default, in the
>     application directory with a file name of application.port).
>
> By default, these writers are not activated, but you can enable:
>
> - By Extending Configuration
> - Section 60.2, “Programmatically”

Here is the 60.1 Extending Configuration part :

> In the META-INF/spring.factories file, you can activate the
>   listener(s) that writes a PID file, as shown in the following example:

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener=\
org.springframework.boot.context.ApplicationPidFileWriter,\
org.springframework.boot.web.context.WebServerPortFileWriter
```

That enables both pid and port output at startup.

So the idea is rather simple : in the `src/main/resources/META-INF` folder of your spring boot application, if not existing, create a `spring.factories` file with the previous content to enable both (pid or port) or with the following to enable only the PID output :

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener=org.springframework.boot.context.ApplicationPidFileWriter
```

Answer (score 1):

Using ApplicationPidFileWriter is one way as already mentioned by @dunni.

Another way would be consuming spring boot actuator. actuator/env will return all the environment details like port#, PID# and many other system properties in json format.

http://hostName:port#/actuator/env

To use this one must first enable and expose actuator in his application.
Steps:

1. Add actuator-starter dependency in pom
2. enable and expose required actuators end points in properties file.

for details refer : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-metrics-endpoint

Comment: op asked whether there is an API to get this pid, so this should get at least a few upvotes.    Here's a json snippet from the /actuator/env endpoint that Arpit mentioned showing an actual pid:                  "PID": {
                    "value": "68112"
                },

Answer (score 0):

No need to use ApplicationPidFileWriter, just use ApplicationPid:

```
SpringApplication springApplication = new SpringApplication(MyApplication.class);
springApplication.run(args);
log.info(new ApplicationPid().toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Just goto /var/run/{your app name}/ ,read the pid in the .pid file .

Answer (score -1):

You could execute the tasklist command to list the active processes and their identificators (PID) will appear.

You could also write them to a file with in the script:

```
tasklist /v txt > filename.txt
```

Afterwards, you can use the script to read the file and get the pid.

Eventually you would use the script to kill the process.